Evenly Distribute Stars on a Sphere According to Categories
I'm working on a project where I need to map stars onto a virtual sphere. The stars must be evenly spaced from each other and from the center of the sphere (0,0,0), with a specific distribution of brightness categories across the sphere's surface. Each segment of the sphere should have a proportional mix of stars based on their brightness, ensuring that the entire sphere is covered uniformly.
Approach and Problem:
Normalization: I started by normalizing the position of each star to form a sphere by scaling their position vectors to a fixed radius.
Even Point Distribution: I generated 1000 evenly spaced points on the sphere using Fibonacci sphere sampling.
Initial Matching: Matching each point to the nearest star worked well without considering star brightness.
Category Distribution: The challenge arises when I try to include a desired distribution of star brightness. The categories need specific ratios across the sphere's surface, but I struggle to maintain an even distribution when categorizing by brightness.
Current Method: My latest attempt involved randomly shuffling the generated points and then assigning them to stars based on their brightness category. For example, every 1.9th point goes to a star of brightness category '8'. However, this method failed to achieve the even distribution required, especially since category '8' stars are rare yet numerous enough to meet the distribution requirements.
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors

def classify_stars(vmag):
    if vmag >= 10:
        return '1'
    elif 7 <= vmag < 10:
        return '3'
    elif 6 <= vmag < 7:
        return '5'
    elif 3 <= vmag < 6:
        return '8'
    elif 1 <= vmag < 3:
        return '9'
    else:
        return '10'

def generate_sphere_points(samples=1000, radius=50):
    points = []
    dphi = np.pi * (3. - np.sqrt(5.))  # Approximation of the golden angle in radians.
    for i in range(samples):
        y = 1 - (i / float(samples - 1)) * 2  # y goes from 1 to -1
        radius = np.sqrt(1 - y * y)  # radius at y

        theta = dphi * i  # golden angle increment
        x = np.cos(theta) * radius
        z = np.sin(theta) * radius

        points.append((x * 50, y * 50, z * 50))
    return np.array(points)

df = pd.read_csv('hygdata_v3.csv', usecols=['hip', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'mag'])
df.dropna(subset=['hip', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'mag'], inplace=True)
df['hip'] = df['hip'].astype(int)
df['norm'] = np.sqrt(df['x']**2 + df['y']**2 + df['z']**2)
df['x'] = 50 * df['x'] / df['norm']
df['y'] = 50 * df['y'] / df['norm']
df['z'] = 50 * df['z'] / df['norm']
df.drop(columns='norm', inplace=True)
df['class'] = df['mag'].apply(classify_stars)

points = generate_sphere_points(samples=1000)
desired_distribution = {'1': 0.27, '3': 0.27, '5': 0.27, '8': 0.19, '9': 0, '10': 0}
total_points = len(points)

# Calculate points per category based on desired distribution
category_points = {k: int(v * total_points) for k, v in desired_distribution.items()}

# Randomly shuffle points to avoid spatial clustering in assignment
np.random.shuffle(points)

sampled_df = pd.DataFrame()
offset = 0

for category, count in category_points.items():
    if count > 0:
        category_stars = df[df['class'] == category]
        nbrs = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=1).fit(category_stars[['x', 'y', 'z']])
        if offset + count > len(points):
            count = len(points) - offset  # Adjust count if it exceeds the number of points
        _, indices = nbrs.kneighbors(points[offset:offset + count])
        unique_indices = np.unique(indices.flatten())
        assigned_stars = category_stars.iloc[unique_indices[:count]]
        sampled_df = pd.concat([sampled_df, assigned_stars], ignore_index=True)
        offset += count

# Output the hip values of stars with category 8 to see if they are evenly distributed
sampled_df = sampled_df.drop_duplicates(subset='hip')

category_8_stars = sampled_df[sampled_df['class'] == '8']
hip_values_category_8 = category_8_stars['hip'].astype(str).tolist()
print(hip_values_category_8)

The dataset can be downloaded here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/EnguerranVidal/HYG-STAR-MAP/main/hygdatav3.csv
Like I said, it is not really wokring the way I imagine.
After two complete days of trying to solve this riddle, I came here for expert advice.
Any idea how I can approach this problem?

Hmm, interesting question. The first thing that comes to mind is to start with a random assignment and then iteratively improve the assignment by random exchanges of single stars or perhaps groups of stars. If you have a metric for uniformity, you can apply a greedy search (only accept a new assignment if it's more uniform) or apply simulated annealing (accept less uniform assignments with some probability) or other heuristic search. There might also be a deterministic layout algorithm; you should probably verify there is no such algorithm before trying a randomized algorithm.

A crude way that will probably work well enough is to cut the sphere into quadrants and require N/8+/-sqrt(N/8) of the N stars of the same brightness to be in each quadrant. If you want better than that my vote would be for swap a pair of stars and simulated annealing. BTW it is a funny distribution of stars in your universe - faint stars are IRL almost exponentially more common starting something like 0.02, 0.06, 0.12, 0.8. See for example stars in each magnitude range and tending towards about 3x more stars each magnitude fainter.

Thanks for the proposed solutions. I will try to implement them for testing.
@MartinBrown - I just want to get a selection of some stars; it should not represent reality but needs to be in the given distribution.

Poisson disc sampling works on a sphere and generates a nice distribution of points.
If you place the stars in order of diminishing brightness/increasing popularity, then you can reduce the disc size as you go to get a pleasing distribution at every scale.

Thanks! Not sure if I understand correctly: What is the advantage of using Poisson disc sampling? The main challenge is matching stars to evenly distributed points on the sphere. How can Poisson disc sampling improve this matching process? What approach should I take to achieve this? Should Poisson disc sampling be used solely to spread the points, which will then serve as reference points for matching stars?

Hmm, I thought you were placing stars on a sphere surface.  You can use Poisson disc sampling to place the bright ones far apart first, and then place the dimmer and dimmer ones, lowering the minimum distance as you go.
